# how can i disable/enable TextFormField based on a selected value from DropDowButton in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dropdownbutton, flutter-textformfield

i'm working on a flutter application and i have created a DropDowButton **menu** with 2 items (**private chat** and **phone number**) and a TextFormField **phonenum**.

when **phone number** is selected, i want to enable the TextFormField **phonenum**. otherwise it's always disable.

is there a way to do this?
thanks in advance!

here's my cod:

```
Widget menu(){
  return DropdownButtonFormField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      labelText: 'select a way to contact with the buyer',
      labelStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 16,
          color: Colors.grey,
          fontFamily: 'Almarai'
        ),
    ),
  items: <String>['phone number', 'private chat'].map((String value) {
    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
      value: value,
      child: Text(value),
    );
  }).toList(),
  onChanged: (String? newValue) {
    setState(() {
      dropdownvalue = newValue!;
    });
  },
);
}

 Widget phonenum(){
    return 
    TextFormField( 
      maxLength: 10,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        labelText: 'phone number',
        labelStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 16,
          color: Colors.grey,
          fontFamily: 'Almarai'
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TextFormField` widget has an `enabled` property which you can use:

```dart
TextFormField(
  enabled: dropdownvalue == 'phone number',
  // ...         
);
```

[Try the full test code on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=b9a4b1d1af2f0182566d283015bd0cd7)

### Screenshots

#### Disabled Field

[image]

#### Enabled Field

[image]